# How to change show/hide to fadein/out?

Tags: jquery, fade

The code was edited from [show hide divs using Next Previous button using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064433/show-hide-divs-using-next-previous-button-using-jquery)

I would like to make a 1000ms fadein/out instead of the sudden show/hide but don't know how to do so.

Here is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/xzk4patd/

HTML:

```
<div class="divs">
<div class="cls1"></div>
<div class="cls2"></div>
<div class="cls3"></div>
</div>

<div id="prev">Prev</div>
<div id="next">Next</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cls1{
    background: red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.cls2{
    background: blue;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.cls3{
    background: green;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
#prev{
    background: gray;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
#next{
    background: orange;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".divs div").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#next").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").hide();
            $(".divs div:first").show();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").hide();
            $(".divs div:last").show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: just change `.show()` to `.fadeIn(1000)` and `.hide()` to `.fadeOut(1000)`

Comment: here your updated [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xzk4patd/7/)

Comment: This kinda works but I don't want #one's postition to be absolute, nor have a top for #prev and #next because I want #prev and #next divs to float underneath the div container, not have an absolute position

Comment: Have a look at my answer, this might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I assume you want to achive s.th. like this:

```
$(".divs > div").each(function (e) {
    if (e != 0) $(this).hide();
});

$("#next").click(function () {
    if ($(".divs > div:visible").next().length != 0) {
        $(".divs > div:visible").fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $(this).next().fadeIn(1000)
        });
    } else {
        $(".divs > div:visible").fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(".divs > div:first").fadeIn(1000);
        });
    }
    return false;
});

$("#prev").click(function () {
    if ($(".divs > div:visible").prev().length != 0) {
        $(".divs > div:visible").fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $(this).prev().fadeIn(1000);            
        });
    } else {
        $(".divs > div:visible").fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(".divs > div:last").fadeIn(1000);
        });

    }
    return false;
});
```

Note that [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) (and `.fadeOut()`) supports a callback-function, which will trigger if the animation is completed. Otherwise your `div` will jump around, demonstrated [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1jj7pu86/).

If you want to float the divs underneath just remove the `position:absolute`. You can also set it to `postion:relative`.

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5yL8a1av/4/)**

Comment: This works well, but my problem is placing a div in the div lists will cause the visibility of all divs to be hidden https://jsfiddle.net/5yL8a1av/1/

Comment: @RobbieFikes see my updated answer, you have to change the selector of the `.each()` -part to hide the divs. The `>` is the direct-sibling-selctor.

Comment: After going through a full iteration the content is visible, but on the second round trip the content doesn't display

Comment: @RobbieFikes yes I see, update all your selectors to reference only the direct child. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".divs div").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    });

    $("#next").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").next().fadeIn('slow').prev().fadeOut('slow');
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut('slow');
            $(".divs div:first").fadeIn('slow');
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").prev().fadeIn('slow').next().fadeOut('slow');
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut('slow');
            $(".divs div:last").fadeIn('slow');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must replace 'hide' with 'fadeOut' and 'show' with 'fadeIn'.
Additionally div's must overlap each other in CSS

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".divs div").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
        $(this).hide();
});

$("#next").click(function(){
    if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
        $(".divs div:visible").next().fadeIn(1000).prev().fadeOut(1000);
    else {
        $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut(1000);
        $(".divs div:first").fadeIn(1000);
    }
    return false;
});

$("#prev").click(function(){
    if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
        $(".divs div:visible").prev().fadeIn(1000).next().fadeOut(1000);
    else {
        $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut(1000);
        $(".divs div:last").fadeIn(1000);
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

CSS:

```
.cls1{
   background: red;
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   position: absolute;
}
.cls2{
background: blue;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
position: absolute;
}
.cls3{
background: green;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
position: absolute;
}
#prev{
background: gray;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
}
#next{
background: orange;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
}
.divs { height: 200px; }
```

Full code: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/xzk4patd/13/)

Comment: That kinda works but when it is on .cls1 it won't go the the previous div (the last one)

Comment: there is a reason why you can't add a fiddle-link without code. Please provide your code in your answer