# How to change show/hide to opacity 0-1 (not fadein/out)?

Tags: jquery, opacity

The code was edited from [show hide divs using Next Previous button using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064433/show-hide-divs-using-next-previous-button-using-jquery)

I would like to make a 1000ms opacity css change to the outer div instead of the sudden show/hide but don't know how to do so. The reason I do not want to use fadein/out is because if I place a div inside a div which is in the div container, the innermost div will have its visibility hidden

Here is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/3y7ty3o7/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="divs">
<div id="one">
    <div class="content-b">
        <h1>KEYS TO SUCCESS</h1>
        <h3>Digial Design Intern</h3>
        <a href="#"><div id="c">LEARN MORE</div></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
</div>
<div>tesstttttttt</div>
<div id="prev">Prev</div>
<div id="next">Next</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cls1{
    background: red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.cls2{
    background: blue;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.cls3{
    background: green;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
#prev{
    background: gray;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
#next{
    background: orange;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".divs div").each(function (e) {
    if (e != 0) $(this).hide();
});

$("#next").click(function () {
    if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0) {
        $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $(this).next().fadeIn(1000)
        });
    } else {
        $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(".divs div:first").fadeIn(1000);
        });
    }
    return false;
});

$("#prev").click(function () {
    if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0) {
        $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $(this).prev().fadeIn(1000);            
        });
    } else {
        $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(".divs div:last").fadeIn(1000);
        });

    }
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: here is my version of solution that I worked yesterday https://jsfiddle.net/xzk4patd/14/ I could not post it since the post was deleted :)

Comment: This is close but how do you iterate when there are divs in a div like this? https://jsfiddle.net/xzk4patd/17/

Comment: Nevermind, works like a charm!!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xzk4patd/18/ it works, you forget to add `class="item"` the the first div

Comment: haha, I wish you did not delete your question yesterday! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.fadeTo(1000, 1)` or `fadeTo(1000, 0)` should do it!

> Adjust the opacity of the matched elements.

https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

Here is demo : https://jsfiddle.net/xzk4patd/18/

Comment: Ok, so then how would I change the javascript so that the div containing the elements (like h1) gets the opacity change? Because right now the code is changing all div's visibility to hidden

Comment: @RobbieFikes in your code you only replaced `.fadeIn(1000)` with `.fadeTo(1000, 1)` and `.fadeOut(1000,` with `.fadeTo(1000, 0)` right? you can also check my example: https://jsfiddle.net/xzk4patd/16/

Comment: @RobbieFikes I wish you did not delete your question yesterday! :)  Can you please mark my answer ?

Comment: One problem, because the opecity gets changed, the content is still there. Is there a way to make the current visible item have the highest index so that links and text are selectable? Here, the 2nd div is not selectable https://jsfiddle.net/xzk4patd/20/