# Display/Hide content with prev/next buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following `jQuery` code which you can also find in the `JSfiddle` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/koanfw15/30/):

```js
/* Code for buttons individually */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".panel_button").on('click', function() {
    $(".panel").hide();
    var targetPanel = $(this).attr('data-target');
     $(targetPanel).show();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});


/* Code for previous and next buttons */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".panel").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#next").click(function(){
        if ($(".panel:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".panel:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
        else {
            $(".panel:visible").hide();
            $(".panel:first").show();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if ($(".panel:visible").prev().length != 0)
            $(".panel:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
        else {
            $(".panel:visible").hide();
            $(".panel:last").show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 500px;
}

.contents {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}

.buttons {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel_button {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

#panel1, #panel2, #panel3 {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contents">

  <div id="panel1" class="panel">
    <div class="content_01a">Here goes content1a</div>
    <div class="content_01b">Here goes content1b</div>
  </div>

  <div id="panel2" class="panel">
    <div class="content_02a">Here goes content2a</div>
    <div class="content_02b">Here goes content2b</div>
    <div class="content_02c">Here goes content2c</div>
  </div>

  <div id="panel3" class="panel">
    <div class="content_03a">Here goes content3a</div>
    <div class="content_03b">Here goes content3b</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="buttons">
  
  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel1"> PREVIOUS </div>

  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel1"> Button_01 </div>
  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel2"> Button_02 </div>
  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel3"> Button_03 </div>
  
  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel1"> NEXT </div>
  
</div>
```

As you can see in the code above I show/hide different `contents` depending on which `button` is clicked. The `button_01` til `button_03` individually work perfectly.

---

Now, I wanted to add a `prev` and `next` button using the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064433/show-hide-divs-using-next-previous-button-using-jquery) but I could not make it work. 
 Do you have any idea what I need to change in the second code within the `jQuery` to make the `prev` and `next` buttons work?

Comment: Just remove the panel button class otherwise you are binding the panel button click too

Comment: @Pete also needs the id on the next/prev button to match the new events

Comment: @freedomn-m ah yeah I presumed that OP would bind to things already there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not updated your next/prev buttons to use your updated code, change:

```
<div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel1"> PREVIOUS </div>
```

to

```
<div id="prev"> PREVIOUS </div>
```

```js
/* Code for buttons individually */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".panel_button").on('click', function() {
    $(".panel").hide();
    var targetPanel = $(this).attr('data-target');
     $(targetPanel).show();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});


/* Code for previous and next buttons */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".panel").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#next").click(function(){
        if ($(".panel:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".panel:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
        else {
            $(".panel:visible").hide();
            $(".panel:first").show();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if ($(".panel:visible").prev().length != 0)
            $(".panel:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
        else {
            $(".panel:visible").hide();
            $(".panel:last").show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 500px;
}

.contents {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}

.buttons {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel_button {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

#panel1, #panel2, #panel3 {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contents">

  <div id="panel1" class="panel">
    <div class="content_01a">Here goes content1a</div>
    <div class="content_01b">Here goes content1b</div>
  </div>

  <div id="panel2" class="panel">
    <div class="content_02a">Here goes content2a</div>
    <div class="content_02b">Here goes content2b</div>
    <div class="content_02c">Here goes content2c</div>
  </div>

  <div id="panel3" class="panel">
    <div class="content_03a">Here goes content3a</div>
    <div class="content_03b">Here goes content3b</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="buttons">
  
  <div id="prev"> PREVIOUS </div>

  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel1"> Button_01 </div>
  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel2"> Button_02 </div>
  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel3"> Button_03 </div>
  
  <div id="next"> NEXT </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man. Exactly what I needed. I also updated it here http://jsfiddle.net/koanfw15/32/

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is you are missing the id's of 'next' and 'prev' buttons as stated. But you do not need additional classes for those only. You can still use your '.panel_button' class on your 'prev' and 'next' buttons. 
This way there is no extra css added.

You only need to take *event propagation* into account then.

```
  $(".buttons").on('click', '.panel_button', function() {
    $(".panel").hide();
    var targetPanel = $(this).attr('data-target');
    $(targetPanel).show();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
```

Check the fiddle out:
https://jsfiddle.net/golala/Lmzrhk4u/

I only changed the way you handled the on click event of '.panel_button'.
This is because your buttons have the same class and if you had your panel_button click event, you would execute this event as well (after you've executed #next/#prev on click). Which gives you the unwanted behaviour.

To prevent this, you only want to implement the on click method on its parent (.buttons) instead. This way you will stop event bubbling with "return false" and you will never execute the method above after #next/#prev on click events.

PS: You do not necessarily need "return false" in this case, because you only want to stop propagation. You can add "e.stopPropagation();" instead of "return false".

This may sound complicated but I suggest you read about 'event bubbling' and 'return false' statement. You will understand the whole issue better then.