# hide and show next item with back button

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

i have code like this:

```js
$('#next').click(function(){
    var $current = $('.question.active');
    // use $current here to test if the question was answered if needed 
    // maybe something like if($current.find('.answer').val().trim() == ''){ return;}
    $('.question').removeClass('active');
    $current.next().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.question:not(.active){
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="questions">
  <div class="question active">Some question 1</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 2</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 3</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 4</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 5</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 6</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 7</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 8</div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
```

i want my code to have a back button
and the next button when at the (question 8) disappear and only the back button remains.

thank you.

Comment: And where is the back button ? where is the code you have tried to achieve what you want ?

Comment: my code haven't back button i want someone put that in my code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [show hide divs using Next Previous button using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064433/show-hide-divs-using-next-previous-button-using-jquery)

Comment: he answered 50% of my question, but I want the next button to be removed when it reaches the last div, and only the back button to remain.That means i want the last div has only the back button

Comment: 'i want someone to put that in my code ' . Why don't you put it in your code ? :) Like you put Next just put Back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#next').click(function() {
  var $current = $('.question.active');
  if ($($current).next(".question").length > 0) {
    $('.question').removeClass('active');
    $current.next().addClass('active');
    buttonCheck();
  }
});
$('#back').click(function() {
  var $current = $('.question.active');
  if ($($current).prev(".question").length > 0) {
    $('.question').removeClass('active');
    $current.prev().addClass('active');
    buttonCheck();
  }
});
buttonCheck();

function buttonCheck() {
  var $current = $('.question.active');
  if ($($current).next(".question").length == 0) {
    $('#next').hide();
    $('#back').show();
  } else if ($($current).prev(".question").length == 0) {
    
    $('#back').hide();
    $('#next').show();
  } else {
    $('#next').show();
    $('#back').show();
  }
}
```

```css
.question:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="questions">
  <div class="question active">Some question 1</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 2</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 3</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 4</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 5</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 6</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 7</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 8</div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="back">Back</button>
<button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`setButtonDisplay()` will hide **Next** button when last div has `active` class, and will hide **Back** button when first div has `active` class.

```js
function setButtonDisplay(){
    var hidePrev = $('#questions div:first').hasClass('active'),
        hideNext = $('#questions div:last').hasClass('active');

    $('#back')[hidePrev ? 'hide' : 'show']();
    $('#next')[hideNext ? 'hide' : 'show']();
}
setButtonDisplay();

$('#next').click(function(){
    var $current = $('.question.active');
    if ($(".question").next().length != 0){
          $('.question').removeClass('active');
          $current.next().addClass('active');
     }
     setButtonDisplay();
});

$('#back').click(function(){
    var $current = $('.question.active');
     if ($(".question").prev().length != 0){
          $('.question').removeClass('active');
          $current.prev().addClass('active');
     }
     setButtonDisplay();
});
```

```css
.question:not(.active){
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="questions">
  <div class="question active">Some question 1</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 2</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 3</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 4</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 5</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 6</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 7</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 8</div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="back">Back</button>
<button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: that **setButtonDisplay()** is nice : )

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do so would be to keep track of the index of the current question.

You'd need to initialize a counter at 1, then increment it (or decrement it) every time you click on the next (or back) button.

Just like that

```js
var counter = 1

$('#next').click(function(){
    var counter = counter++;
    var $current = $('.question.active');
    // use $current here to test if the question was answered if needed 
    // maybe something like if($current.find('.answer').val().trim() == ''){ return;}
    $('.question').removeClass('active');
    $current.next().addClass('active');
});

$('#back').click(function(){
    var counter = counter--;
    var $current = $('.question.active');
    // use $current here to test if the question was answered if needed 
    // maybe something like if($current.find('.answer').val().trim() == ''){ return;}
    $('.question').removeClass('active');
    $current.prev().addClass('active');
});
```

In parallel, write a `.invisible` class this way :

```css
.invisible {
    display: none;
}
```

Finally, you may want to check every time you click on the next/back button whether you need to add or remove this class from the button.

```js
var counter = 1

$('#next').click(function(){
    var counter = counter++;
    var $current = $('.question.active');
    // use $current here to test if the question was answered if needed 
    // maybe something like if($current.find('.answer').val().trim() == ''){ return;}
    $('.question').removeClass('active');
    $current.next().addClass('active');

    if (counter == 8) {
        $('#next').addClass('invisible');
    }

    if (counter == 2){
        $('#back').removeClass('invisible');
    }
});

$('#back').click(function(){
    var counter = counter--;
    var $current = $('.question.active');
    // use $current here to test if the question was answered if needed 
    // maybe something like if($current.find('.answer').val().trim() == ''){ return;}
    $('.question').removeClass('active');
    $current.prev().addClass('active');

    if (counter == 1) {
        $("#back").addClass('invisible');
    }

    if (counter == 7) {
        $("#next").removeClass('invisible');
    }
});
```

I hope it helped!

Comment: Hi,I want the next button to be removed when it reaches the last div, and only the back button to remain.That means i want the last div has only the back button.